# Free official documentation for cables and models?

Tags: tcp, cable, tcpip, documentation

I've been looking through the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) and [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/index.html?WT.mc_id=hpf_logo) sites for official documentation on the Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) model, TCP, and a range of cable standards (5/5e/6). However, other than on the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) site, where it appears I would need to pay 86 swiss francs for a PDF file on the OSI model, I've been unsuccessful in finding official info.

Are there official docs for the Open Systems Interconnection model, TCP, or any of the cable specifications that's free?

Comment: Yes I've tried Google, I've found information (some of it not correct) but was wondering if there are official docs for these topics similar to documentation for programming languages.

Comment: You use three different acronyms there... IOS (apple operating system), OSI (Open Systems Interconnection), and ISO (ISO 9660 file system).

Comment: edited with links/explained acronyms

Comment: ISO is the name of the International Organization for Standardization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization#Name_and_abbreviation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially, standards from the big organizations (ISO, IEEE, TIA) are very expensive to buy. A [full set of TIA/EIA-568 documents](http://global.ihs.com/search_res.cfm?RID=TIA&INPUT_DOC_NUMBER=TIA-568) will set you back almost 1000 USD, for example.

That said, my first search result for "ISO/IEC 7498-1" was a PDF of the OSI spec. Second search result for "TIA/EIA-568" was another PDF.

The TCP/IP and [related internet standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RFCs) are free, as these things probably should be; documented in RFC [791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) and [793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793).

EDIT: Actually, [ISO does give away some of their standards for free](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html). I'm impressed!

Answer (score 0):

Below couple diagrams from http://www.howtogeek.com/70494/what-kind-of-ethernet-cat-5e6a-cable-should-i-use/  that explains difference in speed, power and physical design.

If you are looking for something from IEEE http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/3/tutorial/july98/kish_070798.pdf

or here is search on IEEE site

http://www.ieee.org/searchresults/index.html?cx=006539740418318249752%3Af2h38l7gvis&cof=FORID%3A11&qp=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=cat+cables

Explanation on OSI model from Microsoft:

The Open Systems Interconnect (OSI) model has seven layers. This article describes and explains them, beginning with the 'lowest' in the hierarchy (the physical) and proceeding to the 'highest' (the application). The layers are stacked this way:

```
 Application
 Presentation
 Session
 Transport
 Network
 Data Link
 Physical
```

Full explanation can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103884

[image]

[image]